# Convert datetime ticks(String.Format("{0:D19}", DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks) to datetime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, azure, azure-table-storage

I am storing Azure table storage rowkey in date time ticks format

```
String.Format("{0:D19}", DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks);
```

and I want to convert back to date time.

Comment: What do you want as a result when you convert _back_ to `DateTime`?

Comment: I am just showing all the table details in View.for that i need to convert the ticks into normal date time.

Comment: You can checkout the [Log Tail pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-design-guide#log-tail-pattern) for NoSQL tables too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are doing:

```
string str = String.Format("{0:D19}", DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks);
```

Then we have that

```
// str = max - now
```

so then

```
// now = max - str
```

so

```
DateTime now = new DateTime(DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - long.Parse(str), DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code returns `2519440974768899656` on my timezone which is UTC +02:00 right now, you can parse this string to `long` and can use in `DateTime(long)` constructor.

```
var s = String.Format("{0:D19}", DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks).Dump();
long l = long.Parse(s);
(new DateTime(l)).Dump();
```

Returns

```
16.10.7984 15:31:16
```

But honestly, depending what you doing, I'm *not* quite sure this is the value you want.